# Async map to update an array

Tags: node.js, async.js

I'd like to user `async` module with `map` function to update an array before sending to my view. It seem's not working...

```
async.map(documentations, function(documentation, callback) {
  documentation.content = markdown.toHTML(documentation.content);
  console.log(documentation.content); // => It is ok
  callback(null, documentation);
}, function(err, documentations) {
  console.log(documentations); // => It is not ok, content property as not the new content
  response.render('views/pageShow', {
    documentations: documentations
  });
});
```

Comment: I think that in second callback the `documentations` var points to the global ones. It depends of how you writed the "outer" code, so the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem seems to be that the second parameter 'documentations' is not actually the object you have changed as it is not passed in to the callback. When you call 'callback(null, documentation)' it doesn't actually pass documentation on the final callback, it just iterates to the next part of the structure. The example below may work :

```
async.map(documentations, function(documentation, callback) {
    documentation.content = markdown.toHTML(documentation.content);
    console.log(documentation.content); // => It is ok
    callback(null, documentation);
}, function(err, data) {
    response.render('views/pageShow', {
        documentations: documentations
    });
});
```

As you can see i have changed the second parameter to 'data', this will prevent the confusion between the object you actually want to use (the one being iterated over) and the parameter.